# Generating auto versioning , commenting and committing it to Git

Tags: git, npm, gulp

I was looking for a way to deal with auto versioning for my release **PATCH** (Let's say) in ***Git***. I am trying with the following code in my **package.json** based on Gulp build system.

```
"scripts": {
"build": "gulp build",
"jshint": "gulp hintScripts",
"release-patch": "npm version patch -f",
"release-minor": "npm version minor -f",
"release-major": "npm version major -f",
"preversion": "npm test && npm run build",
"version": "git add -A && git commit -m "Add comment here"",
"test": "npm run jshint",
"postversion": "git push"
},
```

I am using *npm-version* for versioning and in version task I am doing **"git add -A"** for adding all modified files and **"git commit -m "Add comment here"** for committing those files.

When I am running **"npm run release-patch"**, it runs perfect but I can't change my comment(**"Add comment here"**). So please help me out that how can I automate my commenting while committing.